# add a new value to array while keeping existing one

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have below an example of data:

```
{
        "id": "2",
        "items":
            {
              "3" : { "blocks" : { "3" : { "txt" : 'xx' } } },
              "4" : { "blocks" : { "1" : { "txt" : 'yy'}, "2" : { "txt" : 'zz'} } }
            }
         }
```

I want to make it so that it looks like the below example data. Simply append a new value to items.3.blocks.3.txt while keeping existing value of it:

```
 {
        "id": "2",
        "items":
            {
              "3" : { "blocks" : { "3" : { "txt" : 'xx, tt' } } },
              "4" : { "blocks" : { "1" : { "txt" : 'yy'}, "2" : { "txt" : 'zz'} } }
            }
         }
```

I run below but did not make any difference

```
dbx.test.update({"_id": ObjectId("5192264c02a03e374e67d7be")}, {'$addToSet': {'items.3.blocks.0.txt': 'tt'}}, )
```

what should be correct syntax, any help is appreciated...
regards

Comment: I experienced interesting situation, I can not replicate again... When I run $push on items.4.blocks.1.txt it works and dic return to  ..."4" : { "blocks" : { "1" : { "txt" : ['yy', 'tt']}... But it doesnt work still on items.3.blocks.3.txt

Answer (score 0):

I did not realize that this was a mongodb|pymongo question to start with.

```
a = {
    "id": "2",
    "items": {
              "3" : { "blocks" : { "3" : { "txt" : 'xx' } } },
              "4" : { "blocks" : { "1" : { "txt" : 'yy'}, "2" : { "txt" : 'zz'} } }
            }
     }

a['items']['3']['blocks']['3']['txt'] += ', yy'
```

?

Shorter answer on how to modify dicts:

```
a = {'moo' : 'cow', 'quack' : 'duck'}
a['moo'] = 'bull'
a['quack'] = 'duckling'
print(str(a))
if a['moo'] == 'bull':
    print 'Yes the bull says moo'
```

If your data is a JSON string you first need to convert it from a JSON-string to a dictionary in Python, do so by:

```
import json
a = json.loads(<your string goes here>)
```

Comment: Actually I do not convert it to reduce load on system... My aim play to huge data, even if we assume conversion load will be low, I just simply without it... thx

Comment: If that's a JSON string, sorry you're out of luck editing that in any descent way. Also doesn't feel like a good idea to start off your project on :/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ['$push'](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/push/) instead of ['$addToSet'](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/addToSet/):

```
dbx.test.update({"_id": ObjectId("5192264c02a03e374e67d7be")}, {'$push': {'items.3.blocks.0.txt': 'tt'}}, )
```

Comment: for above example push is also does not work... Because it is a string, not an array... if it is like that `"3" : { "blocks" : { "3" : { "txt" : ['xx'] } } }`, it will be work...

Answer (score 0):

is simple, for will work with $addToSet need the data in arrays [ ] but you have the data in `{"key":"value"}`, but you have `{ "blocks" : { "1" : { "txt" : 'yy'}, "2" : { "txt" : 'zz'} } }`, would recommend work in Arrays, Example

```
"items":
           [
              { "algo" : { "blocks" : { "txt" : ['xx']} } } ,
              { "algoo" : { "blocks" : { "txt" : ['yy','zz']} } }
            ]
db.foo.update({"_id":1,"items.algo.blocks.txt":'xx'},{$addToSet:{"items.$.algo.blocks.txt":'tt'}});
```

and no use numbers in fields name.

```
{
        "_id" : 1,
        "items" : [
                {
                        "algo" : {
                                "blocks" : {
                                        "txt" : [
                                                "xx",
                                                "tt"
                                        ]
                                }
                        }
                },
                {
                        "algoo" : {
                                "blocks" : {
                                        "txt" : [
                                                "yy",
                                                "zz"
                                        ]
                                }
                        }
                }
        ]
}
```